# How can I use images as navigation labels for Vue carousel in Vue(Nuxt)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, carousel, nuxt.js

I am using Vue Carousel(https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel). I would like to use the `navigationNextLabel` and `navigationPrevLabel` as images. Meaning, I have 2 images namely, `previous_arrow.png` and `next_arrow.png` that I want to click to slide over this carousel.

But I can't figure out how I can embed images in `:navigationNextLabel` and `:navigationPrevLabel`. This is what I have so far:

```
<template>
<carousel 
  :per-page="1" 
  :mouse-drag="true" 
  :navigation-enabled="true"
  :navigation-next-label="<div><img src="../assets/next_arrow.png" class="w-12 h-12" /></div>"
  :navigation-previous-label="<div><img src="../assets/previous_arrow.png" class="w-12 h-12"/></div>"
>

<slide> Slide content 1 </slide>
<slide> Slide content 2 </slide>
<slide> Slide content 3 </slide>

</carousel>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Gallery extends Vue {
  @Prop() 'navigationEnabled'!: string;
  @Prop() 'navigationNextLabel'!: string;
  @Prop() 'navigationPreviousLabel'!: string;
}
</script>
```

The error I get: `'v-bind' directives require an attribute value.`

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use CSS instead label html. Of course do not forget to hide default button html.

```
.VueCarousel-navigation-button::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 8px;
   height: 25px;
   width: 25px;
}

.VueCarousel-navigation-next::before {
   background: url('../assets/previous_arrow.png');
   right: 6px;
}

.VueCarousel-navigation-prev::before {
   background: url('../assets/previous_arrow.png');
   left: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but I do not see my images show up. I did a display none to the default as you mentioned.

Comment: above is just sample. you need to check image path is correct in css background. Please use chrome inspect and images load normally.